# Excel changing format when exporting to SQL server

Tags: excel, format, adodb, vba

I have data stored in excel and I mean to insert it to SQL server 2008 R2 with a VBA script. There is one column (ID) that is formatted as Special and sometimes may contain just numbers like (Ex: 123456789) and sometimes may contain numbers and letters (Ex: 1A2345678). This column is meant to be imported to a column in SQL server defined as nvarchar(255). The column in excel is formatted with Special Format (ZIP code US). When I INSERT INTO my SQL table the fields that contain only numbers are transformed to scientific notation: 
3522000000004 --> 3.522E+14. 
The reason I formatted the column in excel as ZIP code instead of text is that putting it in Text format transform the code in scientific format and if I make it a number it removes zeros in the beginning of the number.

I am using excel 2010 64 bits.

Thanks!